# Why won't the contents of a jQueryUI tab show within the tab?

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

I'm creating a kind of wizard using jQueryUI tabs. The first tab has the user make a choice from a matrix of images where each image also has a radio button and image title beneath it. For some reason, the images and buttons and title don't show up inside the tab. Here's the site: [link](http://www.ubook247.com/dev/ubook247/edit.php)

And here's the code:

```
<div id="tabs">         <ul>        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Template Choice</a></li>      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Site Basics</a></li>      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Services List</a></li>        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Products/Resources List</a></li>      <li><a href="#tabs-5">Gallery Images</a></li>       <li><a href="#tabs-6">Buzz List</a></li>        <li><a href="#tabs-7">Review &amp; Confirm</a></li>     </ul>       <div id="tabs-1">
                <div>
                    <div class="temp_wrap">

                <img src="images/accordion_t.jpg" alt="accordion" />

                <div class="temp_desc">

                    <p><input type="radio">&nbsp;</input>Accordion</p>

                </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="temp_wrap">

                <img src="images/animation_t.jpg" alt="animation" />

                <div class="temp_desc">

                    <input type="radio">&nbsp;</input>Animation

                </div>
                            </div>
                    <div class="temp_wrap">

                <img src="images/dog_t.jpg" alt="dog" />

                <div class="temp_desc">

                    <input type="radio">&nbsp;</input>Dog

                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>      </div>      <div id="tabs-2">
                <img id="loading" src="/images/loading.gif" style="display:none;">
                <form name="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="site_basics_line">Enter your Name, or your Company's name:<input type="text"></input></div>
                <div class="site_basics_line">Enter your Tagline, or your Company's Tagline:<input type="text"></input></div>

        <div class="site_basics_line">Background Image Upload&nbsp;<input id="fileToUpload" type="file" size="45" name="fileToUpload" class="input">Please select a file and click Upload button<button class="button" id="buttonUpload" onclick="return ajaxFileUpload();">Upload</button></div>

        <div class="site_basics_line">Logo Upload&nbsp;<input id="fileToUpload" type="file" size="45" name="fileToUpload" class="input">Please select a file and click Upload button<button class="button" id="buttonUpload" onclick="return ajaxFileUpload();">Upload</button></div>
                <p>Click here to pick a background color:<input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="#FFFFFF" /><div id="colorpicker"></div></p>
                        </form>
                <a href="#" id="next_2">Next</a>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-3">       <p>
                <div class="site_basics_line">Upload a service icon:&nbsp;<input id="fileToUpload" type="file" size="45" name="fileToUpload" class="input"><button class="button" id="buttonUpload" onclick="return ajaxFileUpload();">Upload</button></div>
                <p>Add a title for this service: <input type="text"></input></p>
                <p>Add a description for this service: <textarea rows="2" cols="20"></textarea></p>
                </p>        <a href="#" id="next_2">Add</a>&nbsp;<a href="#" id="next_3">Next</a>       </div>      <div id="tabs-4">
                <p>
                <div class="site_basics_line">Upload a product or resource icon:&nbsp;<input id="fileToUpload" type="file" size="45" name="fileToUpload" class="input"><button class="button" id="buttonUpload" onclick="return ajaxFileUpload();">Upload</button></div>
                <p>Add a title for this product or resource: <input type="text"></input></p>
                <p>Add a description for this product or resource: <textarea rows="2" cols="20"></textarea></p>
                </p>
            <a href="#" id="next_2">Add</a>&nbsp;<a href="#" id="next_3">Next</a>       <a href="#" id="next_4"></a>        </div>      <div id="tabs-5">       <p>
                <div class="site_basics_line">Add a Gallery Image&nbsp;<input id="fileToUpload" type="file" size="45" name="fileToUpload" class="input">Please select a file and click Upload button<button class="button" id="buttonUpload" onclick="return ajaxFileUpload();">Upload</button></div>
                </p>        <a href="#" id="next_5"></a>        </div>      <div id="tabs-6">
            <div class="site_basics_line">Add a Buzz Image&nbsp;<input id="fileToUpload" type="file" size="45" name="fileToUpload" class="input">Please select a file and click Upload button<button class="button" id="buttonUpload" onclick="return ajaxFileUpload();">Upload</button></div>      <p>Add a link for this Buzz Item: <input type="text"></input></p>       <p>Add a description for this service: <textarea rows="2" cols="20"></textarea></p>         <a href="#" id="next_6"></a>        </div>      <div id="tabs-7">
                <p>Please confirm that you are satisfied with what you have entered and uploaded to your site. When you are, please click the Submit button. Otherwise, you may edit any of the entries made and return to this portion of the site to confirm your site's content. Note that you may return any time to add, edit, or delete the content of your site.</p>         <a href="#" id="next_0"></a>        </div>   </div>
```

All of the other tabs behave normally.

Comment: May I suggest, next time, please simply your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an extra element after all your floating elements to "push" down the container element. So, in your case, add the following line just before the closing tag of `<div id="tabs-1">`:

```
<div style="clear:both; float:none"></div>
```

Comment: You are a champion of the downtrodden. Thanks.